# How can I replace cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin, which is archived, in order to auto-generate runners for Cucumber

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, auto-generate

Trying to figure out if Cucumber-JVM or any other library helps with autogenerating of the cucumber runners during the runtime or should I continue to use cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin, even though it is archived and no longer maintained?

Comment: Why not use the in-built support for parallel execution of cucumber-jvm https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/

Comment: Yea I agree with Grasshopper here,  the repo https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin has a big 'STOP' that tells you not to use it in favor of cucumbers own parallelization.

Comment: That's why I was asking about the replacement of that plugin, because I want to have runner autogeneration feature, which seems to be absent in  jvm library. An I right?

Comment: @Paulus Any specific reason u want to persist with runner autogeneration?

Comment: It's an Automation testing framework and I would like to get rid of custom cucumber runner inside of it.

Comment: You can try running it directly using the cucumber class cucumber.api.cli.Main from the command prompt using the --threads option. No need for runners at all.

Comment: I need to run both feature files and via command prompt without an explicitly created runner.

Comment: @Paulus any progress here? I need same thing as you - cucumber-jvm is not able to auto-generate runners which is must for me.

Comment: @medy it was not a must for me, I just wanted a better solution. My team keeps using created runner for every environment and so do I. I would take a a look at last Grasshopper comment und running Features via command line.